# This circle properties problem I have been looking at the problem and trying to fix it and keep getting the same problem:

Tags: python

I need to write a subroutine that outputs the following properties of a circle from the diameter and arc angle: the radius of the circle(diameter divided by 2) the area f the circle (3.14 multiplied by the radius squared) the circumference of the circle (3.14 multiplied by the diameter) the arc length (circumference multiplied by the arc angle), divided by 360.

And I get this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Charlie\so.py", line 26, in <module>
    print("This is the circle area: " + circleArea())
  File "c:\Users\Charlie\so.py", line 13, in circleArea    
    circleAre = str(3.14*radius**2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int'
```

[my code attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnd4B.png)

Comment: try `radius()` instead of `radius` - you want _the number the function returns_, not _the function itself_.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that will still break since `radius()` returns `str`

Comment: What @GreenCloakGuy means is that you need to put `radius()` in the `circleArea` function, otherwise you're just referring to the function itself rather than the return.

Cast it to a float and it should be fine.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

```
def circleArea():
    circleAre = str(3.14*float(radius())**2)
    return circleAre
```

This way, you're calling the function and getting the return as a float, which in turn makes the calculation valid.